# Update location every 15 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a GPS app and I have been able to successfully get location updates. However, these updates are coming way to fast (~1-2 seconds). I want to be able to update the UILabel every 15 seconds instead. What is wrong with my code?

P.S. `[self setLabels:manager];` simply sets UILabels to the value of managers properties:

`manager.location.coordinate.latitude` & `longitude:manager.location.coordinate.longitude`

Thanks!

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
    //SHOULD BE LOOPING INTO HERE EVERY 15 SECONDS. INSTEAD IT IS 1-2 SECONDS
    [self setLabels:manager];
  }
}
```

Comment: CLLocationManager is not allowed to be scheduled. Set `locationManager.distanceFilter` to some value like 20 meters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an iVar like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastUpdatedTime;
```

Then just check if the `lastUpdatedTime` is more than 15 sec ago (or nil for the first time) and update the date every time you set the labels.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if( [self.lastUpdatedTime timeIntervalSinceNow] > 15 || self.lastUpdatedTime == nil ){
        [self setLabels:manager];
        self.lastUpdatedTime = [NSDate date];
    }
}
```

This way you can keep the GPS updates how they are suppose to work. But only update the labels every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

GPS is not something you can schedule, meaning when you start monitoring location you will get a lot of location update because the GPS signal is getting better.

Especially in the beginning you want to update more then just every 15 seconds, because you are getting a better GPS fix.

You should rethink you code and maybe compare location results to determine if you need to update the label.

Comment: Thanks! You seem to have to know what your talking about. I am fairly new to this, can you provide an example of what you mean? Thanks

Comment: The if statement is wrong. Getting location and displaying location are separate concerns. The GPS will continue to update and get more accurate in the background with the current code.

Comment: @user3071962, Yes that is true. But I'm just addressing a hole other issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because 1 is less than 15, your code should be

```
if (abs(howRecent) >= 15.0) {
    //SHOULD BE LOOPING INTO HERE EVERY 15 SECONDS. INSTEAD IT IS 1-2 SECONDS
    [self setLabels:manager];
}
```

Comment: With the current code the if statement will never be true. howRecent will always be very small. Roland Keesom has it right.

Answer (score -1):

Every 15 second it call background mode and fetch data

```
double delayInSeconds = 15.0;
dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
^(void){
    //your code here
});
```